# Letter 'A' is rendered strangely in mac browsers

Tags: css, wordpress, browser, fonts

I am developing a website, and I noticed a very odd issue, the **letter 'A'** is displayed strangely on my Mac, but it is displayed correctly on my iPhone. It affects many fonts (eg. Montserrat, Inter..)
I tried Safari, Chrome, Firefox and even Edge, with the same result, but as I said it is displayed correctly on my iPhone. Does anyone have a clue what this could be?

[Image: Strange 'A'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oCsx.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no issue with the code, this is purely a visual problem. Does anyone have an idea? It is very frustrating :(